# Venetian blind cross validation?

Tags: cross-validation

Is Venetian blind cross validation a type of K-fold cross validation methods? I'm having trouble finding a reference to what the difference may be.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of Venetian blind cross-validation, but apparently it is a thing, and I've used it in the past without realizing it had a name.  [This site](https://wiki.eigenvector.com/index.php?title=Using_Cross-Validation) gives a definition, along with some others:

Venetian Blinds: Each test set is determined by selecting every sth object in the data set, starting at objects numbered 1 through s.

Contiguous Blocks: Each test sets is determined by selecting contiguous blocks of n/s objects in the data set, starting at object number 1.

Random Subsets: s different test sets are determined through random selection of n/s objects in the data set, such that no single object is in more than one test set. This procedure is repeated r times, where r is the number of iterations. It is the averaged results of the iterations that is used in the report of the cross validation results.

Leave-One-Out: Each single object in the data set is used as a test set.

Custom: Each of the test sets is manually defined by the user. Provisions can be made to "force" specific objects to be in every test set, never be in a test set, or not be used in the cross validation procedure at all.